# How to include a dependency from @ModuleA, in @ModuleB using Dagger2 in Java

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

I am using Dagger2 for dependency injection in quite a large project.
There are 2 different sections of the app that each use multiple usecases.
For each section I have a module that provides the dependencies for that section. I have come across a scenario where I need to use a usecase from  moduleA in ModuleB and I am not sure how to include it or add it to be used for that one scenario.I have looked at other answers on stackoverflow but have not found one that answers my question.

For example this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50108369/from-one-dagger2-module-how-to-access-the-sharedpreferences-provided-in-another)

does not help me because it's setup is different and I cannot deduce from this solution how to solve my problem.

and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32146077/internal-dependency-injection-using-dagger2)

I am not certain that I should make any of these dependencies into Singletons.

for example I have ModuleA below that contains *AddItem* that I need in ModuleB *PayForItem*

```
@Module
public class ModuleA {

    private final FragmentActivity mActivity;

    public ModuleA(FragmentActivity fragmentActivity) {
        mActivity = fragmentActivity;
    }
...

  @Provides
  AddItem addItemPresenter(DateMapper dataMapper, ItemdetailUseCase itemDetailUsecase){
        return new AddItem(dataMapper,itemDetailUsecase);
    }



@Module
    public class ModuleB {

        private final FragmentActivity mActivity;

        public ModuleB(FragmentActivity fragmentActivity) {
            mActivity = fragmentActivity;
        }
    ...

      @Provides
      PayForItem payForItemPresenter(AddItem addItem){
            return new AddItem(addItem);
        }
```

Each module is included in its own subcomponent eg:

```
@Subcomponent(modules = {ModuleA.class})
public interface ModuleAPresentationComponent {
    void inject(Fragment testFragment;
}


@Subcomponent(modules = {ModuleB.class})
public interface ModuleBPresentationComponent {
    void inject(Fragment testFragment;
}
```

Both are included in the main component eg:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {ApplicationModule.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    public ModuleAPresentationComponent newPresentationComponent(ModuleAPresentationModule presentationModule);
    public ModuleBPresentationComponent newPresentationComponent(ModuleBPresentationModule presentationModule);
}
```

I have a BaseFragment that I use to inject eg:

```
public abstract class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

    private boolean mIsInjectorUsed;
    protected static final String PARAM_USER_ID = "param_user_id";

    private ApplicationComponent getApplicationComponent() {
        return ((AndroidApplication) getActivity().getApplication()).getApplicationComponent();
    }

    @UiThread
    protected ModuleAPresentationComponent getModuleAPresentationComponent() {
        if (mIsInjectorUsed) {
            throw new RuntimeException("there is no need to use injector more than once");
        }
        mIsInjectorUsed = true;
        return getApplicationComponent()
                .newPresentationComponent(new ModuleAPresentationModule(getActivity()));
    }

    @UiThread
    protected ModuleBPresentationComponent getModuleBPresentationComponent() {
        if (mIsInjectorUsed) {
            throw new RuntimeException("there is no need to use injector more than once");
        }
        mIsInjectorUsed = true;
        return getApplicationComponent()
                .newPresentationComponent(new ModuleBPresentationModule(getActivity()));
    }
```

So in my fragment it injects like this:

```
public class testFragment extends BaseFragment{

 @Inject AddItem addItemPresenter;

       @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            getModuleAPresentationComponent().inject(this);
        }
}
```

How would I use *AddItem* from ModuleA in *PayForItem* ModuleB without repeating those dependencies in ModuleB?

Comment: Each module provides dependency for a specific scope. So if you try to reuse the  the scoping might go wrong. I would suggest to repeat the dependencies in Module B.  But would like to know if any specific reason why are you avoiding the repetition?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have a basic understanding of Dagger2 so I first wanted to check if there was a way to include or add the needed dependency from one Module to the other, instead of just repeating. But if repeating is ok in this instance then that makes it quite easy to solve.

Comment: Although you can try creating ModuleBPresentationComponent using ModuleB as well as ModuleA. And try accessing the objects that are created in ModuleA.

Comment: I made a module for repeated dependencies. But It feels like overkill. I think maybe it would be better to just expand the scope between modules, so create one subComponent that takes in all the modules so any dependency can be used where it is needed?